# How to import a python inside a fixture and use them as global variables for each test in Pytest?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, pytest, ui-testing

I'm trying to automate UI tests for a Django app with `SeleniumWebDriver` and I wanted to integrate Pytest because we are already using it for Unitary tests, and I would like to have a folder with profiles according to the specific environment like local, production or staging with a bunch of variables, so we can run Pytest with a specific profile.

I want different files like local, staging and production with different variables values but the same schema, and use them inside each test like they were global variables.

I tried to use a fixture inside the `conftest.py` file, but it gives me an error saying that I cannot import a whole module.

Is there a way to have anything like profiles for all tests in pytest and change it with an argument?

I would like to do something like:

`pytest --profile=local`

And automatically all test run with the variables defined in a `local.py` file. This is an idea i had, but any advise is welcome so I can implement this in some other way.

Comment: You can use `pytest-django` plugin which supports test-specific settings files. If this is not what you need, best is to add a real-world usage example of the custom profiles that doesn't fit into existing settings.

Answer (score 0):

It can be the next format of config:

```
class Config:
    def __init__(self, env):
        self.base_url = {
            'local': 'https://local-env.com',
            'prod': 'https://prod-env.com',
            'stage': 'https://stage-env.com',
        }[env]

        self.app_port = {
            'local': 8080,
            'prod': 80,
            'stage': 1111
        }[env]
```

In that case the conftest.py will be:

```
from pytest import fixture

from config import Config


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--env", 
        action="store",
        help="Environment to run tests against"
    )

@fixture(scope='session')
def env(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--env")

@fixture(scope='session')
def app_config(env):
    cfg = Config(env)
    return cfg
```

And test:

```
def test_environment_is_staging(app_config):
    base_url = app_config.base_url
    port = app_config.app_port
    assert base_url == 'staging'
```

The usage will be like:

```
pytest --env=stage
```